# Disable default Internet app on Android 6.0.1 on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internet, uninstallation, disable-app

I'm trying to disable the default "Internet" app. I can't deactivate it via the app manager. I need it disabled, because the Tablet should not be allowed to use an internet browser, but other apps should still be able to connect to the internet. The device is hardened and only a few apps are allowed. But through the settings the user can reach the user manual, which opens the default internet app. Therefore I need to uninstall or disable it.

Has anybody an idea how to get rid of built in apps without rooting the device?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/:

> **WARNING** Uninstalling system applications can be dangerous so please know what you’re getting rid of before you complete these steps. Failing to do so could result in your phone becoming unusable until you perform a factory reset. Of course, by removing any given system application, another system application that may depend on it may also break so be careful what you remove.

1. Install the USB drivers for your device (Google has a list of some universal USB drivers [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html))
2. Download the [ADB binary](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads/) for your particular OS ([Windows](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip), [Mac](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-darwin.zip), [Linux](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip))
3. Extract the zip file into a folder that you can quickly access.
4. 

On your phone, go to Settings and tap on About Phone. Find the Build Number and tap on it 7 times to enable Developer Options.
4.
Now enter Developer Options and find USB Debugging. Enable it.
5.
Plug your phone into the computer and change it from "charge only" mode to "file transfer (MTP)" mode.
6.
On your computer, browse to the directory where you extracted the ADB binary.
7.
Launch a Command Prompt in your ADB folder. For Windows users, this can be done by holding Shift and Right-clicking then selecting the “open command prompt here” option.
8.
Once you're in the command prompt/terminal, enter the following command: `adb devices`
9.
You will see that the system is starting the ADB daemon. If this is your first time running ADB, you will see a prompt on your phone asking you to authorize a connection with the computer. Grant it.
10.
Now if you re-run the `adb devices` command, the terminal will print the serial number of your device. If so, then you’re ready to move on.
11.
Enter the following command: `adb shell`
12.
Execute the `pm list packages | grep '<OEM/Carrier/App Name>'` command to find `package names.package list`

> **ALTERNATIVELY:** You can also easily find the package name of an installed system application by installing the [App Inspector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ubqsoft.sec01) app on your phone. I prefer doing it this way so you know exactly what the app name is of the application that you are about to uninstall.

---

### **If you have App Inspector follow the steps below:**

Step 1: Tap on "App List"

Step 2: Find the app you want to uninstall. (eg. "Compass")

Step 3: Find the package name under the App Name (eg. "com.huawei.compass")

---

14. 

Execute the command like so: `pm uninstall -k --user 0 <name of package>` command to uninstall a specific system application.

Comment: Shouldn't pre-emptive death warnings come BEFORE, so impatient people have to read it first? Last may be too late for some who like the ideas of following numbered instructions (in order, (always in order)).

Comment: @wbogacz Thanks for the advice. Will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Samsung Internet has the package name `com.sec.android.app.sbrowser`

Comment: After uninstalling, you can easily reinstall Samsung Internet from the Galaxy Store or Google Play.

Comment: Note that these commands *disable* an application, instead of completely uninstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Settings > Applications > Application manager and navigate to all apps tab then found your browser in this list and tap on it and then you see turn off button, when you disable it using this button, browser should disappear from applications menu. If this is not working for you, there is no other way, you will need to root your tablet.

**Update:**

After you root your device, you need to download root explorer, total commander or ESFile Manager and go to system/app where you should find browser and delete or cut it from here. 
**IF YOU DELETE IT FROM HERE, THERE WILL BE NO WAY TO RESTORE THIS WITHOUT REFLASHING ENTIRE ROM!**

But there is a second way, which I recommend to you. With downloading Titanium Backup from Google Play Store and freezing your browser from this powerful app. After this you could restore it any time you want.

Comment: OP already stated: "I can't deactivate it via the app manager." So that only leaves the "root option". But rooting alone won't solve the issue; maybe you could [edit] your answer and include how to solve the issue if the device is rooted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've already tried it via the application manager, but for the browser the "deactivate" button is not clickable. Do I need to root my device for using the Titanium Backup app?

Comment: Update: Root is needed for this app, but no option for me because the tablet is used for working purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Download "Package disabler" from google playstore,open it and scroll down to find "internet" disable it,it automatically vanishes from your app drawer.You dont need to need root access.

Answer (score 0):

Go to app manager, select Samsung Internet, then disable all permissions, you will reach a point where you are asked if you would like to uninstall all updates and to go back to the factory stock of the app, just click ok.  It will uninstall, and when you go to your default apps, Samsung Internet is no longer there.  Just did this!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, on Android 10.